# Not secure error in the election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election, ssl

In the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), there is **Connection is Not Secure** error occurred due to the images.

> [image: Not secure error]

On the high level, when I was checked all the user accounts displayed on the page were `https://`, so when I check the Media part of the page, there is a user profile contains a `.png` file with `http://`, that caused the not secure error.

> [image: .png that caused the error]